# jQuery combobox plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for jQuery plugin that does something very similar to [google translate](http://translate.google.com/) when you click on 'detect language'.  I couldn't find this in jQuery UI - is there anything out there?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/index.html and, for the combobox code, http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/closure_goog_ui_menubuttonrenderer.js.source.html